# Find the maximum value in a specfic column that contains both numeric and string data types

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that contains a column(for example 'langtitude') that contains both numeric and string data type.
For example: [5, "high","3"]

I want to change the rows that contains text data(for example "high"), to the max value in column( for example '5'), Which method/ function would you use?
Thank you.

I Wanted to use The df['latitude'].max() function, but it cant compare between string and numeric data type.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pd.to_numeric method to convert the values in the latitude column to numeric.
Then you are going to use .fillna any NaN values with the max value you got.
P.S. The errors='coerce' means any non-numeric you get, pandas will make it into a NaN.

```
import pandas as pd

yourData = {'latitude': [5, "high", "3"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(yourData)

MaxValues = pd.to_numeric(df['latitude'], errors='coerce').max()

df['latitude'] = pd.to_numeric(df['latitude'], errors='coerce').fillna(MaxValues)

print(df)
```

```
   latitude
0       5.0
1       5.0
2       3.0
```

Comment: @gtomer Your anser seems to be changing the order of the original df. Isnt it better to maintain the order ?
Also DataFrame.applymap seems to be deprecated, so why not a future proof solution ?

Comment: I'd just avoid using twice `to_numeric`: `s = pd.to_numeric(df['langtitude'], errors='coerce') ; df['langtitude'] = s.fillna(s.max())`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
df[df.map(np.isreal)].fillna(pd.to_numeric(df['latitude'], errors='coerce').max())


   latitude
0       3.0
1       5.0
2       5.0
```

Comment: [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) say: *Deprecated since version 2.1.0: DataFrame.applymap has been deprecated. Use DataFrame.map instead.* Shouldn't this be mentioned?

Comment: @OCa - changed to `map`